# Button Visibilty inside a Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

i've created a Datagrid Control in WPF. how can i make my Button visible only for a Cell

inside the row that i have select it.
anyone can help.

```
XAML:
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="typ" Header="H." Width="50">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
     <Button Name="btnTabelle" Visibility="Hidden" Height="20" Width="25" 
             Click="Button_Table_Click">

     </Button>
   </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Please show some code, so people can help

Comment: Detail template may be what you are looking for: [DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate Property (System.Windows.Controls)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowdetailstemplate.aspx)

Comment: @Blam - I don't think he needs RowDetails in this issue. The answer of Rachel is what he needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Visibility based on if the `DataGridCell.IsSelected`, although you will need a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx) to convert the boolean value to a `Visibility` one

Here's an example, using a `RelativeSource` binding to find the `DataGridCell`

```
 <Button Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},
             Converter={StaticResource MyBooleanToVisibiltyConverter}" ... />
```

Comment: thanx for ur solution, right now my button is Visible if i select a row, the problem is the button should be visible only if i select a row and then press a button that i defined in my Ribbon Tab after that my Button schould be Visible

Comment: @User1979 In that case, you'll need to create your own `IMultiValueConverter` since your visibility will be based on two databound values instead of 1